# "SSL is required" while uploading a patchset to gerrit

Tags: git, ssl, android-source, gerrit

I uploaded the first patchset to the AOSP gerrit from a build server. Now that I don't have access to that build server I cherry-picked the patch to the aosp source on my laptop.
I followed the tutorial with adding login details at `~/.netrc` file. I did repo start `repo start kitkat-dev .`.
I made the required changes in my project, amended the commit
then `repo upload .` from the `frameworks/base` dir. But I'm getting the following error :

```
Upload project frameworks/base/ to remote branch refs/tags/android-4.4_r1.2:
branch kitkat-dev ( 1 commit, Tue May 6 10:24:34 2014 +0530):
     f9c3e36d Broadcast an intent to mediascanner after executing screencap
to android-review.googlesource.com (y/N)? y
fatal: remote error: SSL is required

----------------------------------------------------------------------
[FAILED] frameworks/base/ kitkat-dev      (Upload failed)
```

I couldn't find anything related to this on internet.
Anyone has any idea what may be the reason or shoudl I sync the source again ?